# How do I dynamically create a read-only contract in Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf

My attorney gave me a 10 page contract that we need to fill in the blanks with the client name, pricing etc and then provide the client with a PDF or equivalent of the contract.

I have looked at PDF::Create but it looks like I would have to create the entire document through code, not just the the placeholders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CAM::PDF](http://p3rl.org/CAM::PDF), [PDF::API2](http://p3rl.org/PDF::API2) can modify existing documents. Your question is not very specific, so no code example.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using a templating system and LaTeX rather than making the pdf by hand.